# Is "I bought it because it costed ..." an idiomatic and grammatical phrase?

Tags: phrase-usage, syntax, morphology

I thought the phrase was common. Example sentence:

> Naomi bought the coffee because it costed ¥499, and she was obsessed
>   with prime numbers.

However, Google only yields [4](https://www.google.com.tw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22bought%20it%20because%20it%20costed%22) results. This makes me suspect there's something wrong with the phrase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you found so few results is most likely because *cost* is an irregular verb. The past simple (and the past participle, too) of *cost* is still *cost*, so the correct phrase would be:

*Naomi bought the coffee because it cost ¥499 [...]*

[You can find many lists of these verbs on the Internet.](http://speakspeak.com/resources/vocabulary-general-english/english-irregular-verbs)